# Vegetation classification for aerial photography in QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, classification, aerial-photography, vegetation-index

What I need to do is to use **QGIS**, for **vegetation classification** of some older and newer
Aerial Photography.  In the past we have used ERADS Imagine but I have seen that there is some plugin developed by Luca Congedo.

Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin

The Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin (SCP) allows for the supervised classification of remote sensing images, providing tools for the download, the preprocessing and postprocessing of images.  This only seems to accomodate satellite imagery.

My question is there any tools/plugins developed for standard **NIR** and **RGB** aerial imagery.
We would try to do phase 1 and phase 2 vegetation classification and get values for **NDVI**.

Primarily for **QGIS**.

Comment: If you are looking for an open-source alternative you should consider Orfeo Toolbox.  See this link:  https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/  and this link for supervised classifications help:   https://rossedwards.co.uk/blog/2019/03/15/assisted-classification-with-orfeo-toolbox-otb/   Orfeo support within QGIS may be limited or non-existent depending on the QGIS version you are using.

Comment: Vegetation health indices are available to the QGIS user via the raster calculator.  See this link to get you started:  https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/remote-sensing-with-qgis-calculate-ndvi/